# Difference between Hadoop and Nosql

Tags: hadoop, nosql

I would like to know the basic difference between hadoop and nosql

- What is the need of Hadoop?
- What is the need of NoSQL?
- Are both same?

Answer (score 38):

[Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) refers to an ecosystem of software packages, including MapReduce, HDFS, and a whole host of other software packages to support the import and export of data into and from HDFS (the Hadoop Distributed FileSystem). When someone says, "I have a Hadoop cluster," they generally mean a cluster of machines all running in this general ecosystem with a large distributed filesystem to support large scale computation.

NoSQL is referring to non-relational or at least non-SQL database solutions such as [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/) (also a part of the Hadoop ecosystem), [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/), [MongoDB](http://mongodb.org/), [Riak](http://basho.com/products/riak-overview/), [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/), and many others.

Hadoop - computing framework

NoSQL  - Not Only - SQL databases

Comment: A very clear explanation of the differences, thank you.

Answer (score 9):

According to Wikipedia:

[Hadoop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadoop):

> Apache Hadoop is an open-source software framework that supports data-intensive distributed applications, licensed under the Apache v2 license.[1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/bigdata/nosql-hadoop-1654158.html) It enables applications to work with thousands of computational independent computers and petabytes of data.

[NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL):

> In computing, NoSQL (mostly interpreted as "not only SQL"[1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/bigdata/nosql-hadoop-1654158.html)) is a broad class of database management systems identified by its non-adherence to the widely used relational database management system model; that is, NoSQL databases are not primarily built on tables, and as a result, generally do not use SQL for data manipulation.

They are not the same thing, but are related to data inten. Hadoop is an entire framework (that can be used with NoSQL DBMS [like Oracle NoSQL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/bigdata/nosql-hadoop-1654158.html)).

Answer (score 6):

I think your questions leads in the wrong direction.

hadoop is the name for a distributed filesystem called hdfs and a possibility to use the map reduce paradigm for large scale calculations. Since yarn it is also possible to use a hadoop cluster with a lot more tasks (like storm, hive, etc.).

nosql refers to databases not queried by sql and not necessarily use tables etc.

you may want to have a look at the wiki pages of [hadoop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadoop) and [noSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) for further understanding of the differences between both